# #include <mapix.h> missing Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Hi I recently installed Visual Studio 2012 and converting one of my projects that uses the header files:

```
#include <mapi.h>
#include <mapix.h>
#include <mapiutil.h>
```

I see the new include directory is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um` but it only has the mapi.h header file not the other two and I am getting the error cannot open file.

Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not part of the Windows SDK, it is available as a [separate download](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206113625/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12905).

Comment: Hi, Thanks I had tried that download and selected the um folder but it seems it is installing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include` is having VS2010 installed also the problem?

Comment: It is just old and not yet aware of the version 8 SDK.  Just tell the compiler to also look in that include directory.

Comment: Or install the files to another folder that the compiler looks in

Comment: Link is now broken. Hopefully this follows the download around: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/how-to-install-mapi-header-files

Comment: The links have once again broken. Even Microsoft's own MAPI examples now have broken links.

Comment: I found a copy used by Thunderbird here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1439660

I haven't tried them yet, tho