# #include <mapiutil.h>, #include<mapiwin.h> missing Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I recently installed Visual Studio 2012 and i am converting one of my projects that uses the header files:

```
 #include <mapiutil.h>
 #include <mapiwin.h>
```

I am getting the error:

> error c1083: cannot open include: 'mapiutil.h': no such file or directory.

Can anyone help to resolve this error?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7843071f-0767-4af4-b645-508e3ffcf56f/visual-c-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765447/include-mapix-h-missing-visual-studio-2012

Comment: thanks for reply i downloaded one software which contains those header files, i added the path in additional include directories(project/properites/..) . iam getting different errors.